# How can I verify event (click) binding through an attribute directive?

Tags: angular

I am currently working on some shared code that needs to be accessible for users who can't use mouse navigation. There's a lot of elements that have had their click event bound to handlers.

```
<div ngFor="let user of users">
    <div class="link" (click)="addOrEditUser(user.Id)">{{ user.Name }}</div>
</div>
```

Because this elements need to support both click and keypress events I defined the following directive to help me trigger the click handler only when the user presses the "Enter" key.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy, HostListener, HostBinding, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[keyboardClick]',
})
export class KeyboardClickDirective implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    eventListenerRef: any;
    @HostBinding('attr.tabindex') tabIndexValue: number;

    @Output('click')
    emmiter = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        console.log('this should have a click event', elementRef);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (!this.tabIndexValue) this.tabIndexValue = 0;
    }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    enterPressed(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            this.emmiter.emit(e);
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {}
}
```

I had to do this, because I can't refactor all the individual handlers of the click event to support keypressed also.

Now my template looks a bit like this:

```
<div ngFor="let user of users">
    <div class="link" (click)="addOrEditUser(user.Id)" keyboardClick>{{ user.Name }}</div>
</div>
```

My code does what I need but I'd like to throw an error if the element doesn't have a click binding.

TL;DR
This should throw an error:

```
<div ngFor="let user of users">
    <div class="link" keyboardClick>{{ user.Name }}</div>
</div>
```

This shouldn't throw an error:

```
<div ngFor="let user of users">
    <div class="link" (click)="addOrEditUser(user.Id)" keyboardClick>{{ user.Name }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to capture the keyboard click event.

```
<div ngFor="let user of users">
    <div class="link" (keyboardClick)="addOrEditUser($event)">{{ user.Name }}</div>
</div>
```